# How to make the cumulative grouping till specific condition breaks in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests, pandas-groupby

I have a data as follows:

```
    User    Activity    Time(In Mins)
0   1       A           2.00
1   1       B           1.00
2   1       C           1.20
3   1       D           3.00
4   1       A           7.20
5   1       D           0.47
6   1       B           10.00
7   2       A           4.00
8   2       B           6.00
9   2       C           10.00
10  2       F           1.00
11  2       G           2.50
```

I want to sessions:
1 session consists of multiple activities. Session breaks if some activity takes more than 5 mins and after that I have to count another session.

I have data in lakhs so I want quickest way to do it

desired output:

```
    User    Activity    Time(In Mins)  Session
0   1       A           2.00           1
1   1       B           1.00           1
2   1       C           1.20           1
3   1       D           3.00           1
4   1       A           7.20           1
5   1       D           0.47           2          
6   1       B           10.00          2
7   2       A           4.00           1
8   2       B           6.00           1
9   2       C           10.00          2
10  2       F           1.00           3
11  2       G           2.50           3
```

Comment: greater than 5 minutes or equals or greater than 5 minutes?

Comment: @Corralien  greater than 5 minutes.

Comment: @JamesZ May I know why?

Comment: @Kyra Because us who don't live in India do not use or know Indian words? And there's universal words that everyone else uses, like "a million" or "hundred thousand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean mask. First, find all values greater than 300 seconds then group by user and `cumsum`. Finally, add 1 and shift all values according your expected result:

```
mask = (df['Time(In Mins)'] // 1 * 60) + (df['Time(In Mins)'] % 1 * 100) > 5 * 60
df['Session'] = mask.groupby(df['User']).cumsum().add(1).shift(fill_value=1)
```

```
>>> df
    User Activity  Time(In Mins)  Session
0      1        A           2.00        1
1      1        B           1.00        1
2      1        C           1.20        1
3      1        D           3.00        1
4      1        A           7.20        1
5      1        D           0.47        2
6      1        B          10.00        2
7      2        A           4.00        3
8      2        B           6.00        1
9      2        C          10.00        2
10     2        F           1.00        3
11     2        G           2.50        3
```

Comment: Why the complicated breakdown of the time? `df['Time(In Mins)'].gt(5)` should be sufficient. I don't think values like `4.60` would be used ;)

Comment: if you want to use shift method, you should have coded like this

`mask.groupby(df['User']).cumsum().add(1).groupby(df['User']).shift(fill_value=1)`

that is one more time `groupby(df['User'])`

but i could learn what shift method is by your code. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df['Session'] = ((df['Time (in Mins)'].shift(1) > 5.) & \
                 (df.User == df.User.shift(1))).astype(int)
df['Session'] = df.groupby('User')['Session'].transform(np.cumsum) + 1

#   User Activity  Time (in Mins)  Session
#0      1        B            1.00        1
#1      1        C            1.20        1
#2      1        D            3.00        1
#3      1        A            7.20        1
#4      1        D            0.47        2
#5      1        B           10.00        2
#6      2        A            4.00        1
#7      2        B            6.00        1
#8      2        C           10.00        2
#9      2        F            1.00        3
#10     2        G            2.50        3
```

Comment: you should add  code this below in final line :

`df.loc[(df['Time (in Mins)']>5),'Session']=df['Session']-1`

Answer (score -1):

in my case i just did

```
df['Session'], df.loc[df['Session']!=1,'Session']=(df.groupby('User').cumcount()+1),0 # make 1 in fist observation by User
df['Session']=df['Session']+(df['Time(In Mins)']>5)
df['Session']=df['Session'].groupby(df['User']).cumsum()
df.loc[(df['Time(In Mins)']>5),'Session']=df['Session']-1

#    User Activity  Time(In Mins)  Session
#0      1        A           2.00        1
#1      1        B           1.00        1
#2      1        C           1.20        1
#3      1        D           3.00        1
#4      1        A           7.20        1
#5      1        D           0.47        2
#6      1        B          10.00        2
#7      2        A           4.00        1
#8      2        B           6.00        1
#9      2        C          10.00        2
#10     2        F           1.00        3
#11     2        G           2.50        3
```

but I don't like final line in my code because I wanted to "directly" indicate value in right-above observation(just like stata's `variable[_n-1]`, where _n means current observation). anyway i also add how you should code your work in Stata below.

```
clear
edit


* data

input  user str1(activity) time
1 "A" 2.00
1 "B" 1.00
1 "C" 1.20
1 "D" 3.00
1 "A" 7.20
1 "D" 0.47
1 "B" 10.00
2 "A" 4.00
2 "B" 6.00
2 "C" 10.00
2 "F" 1.00
2 "G" 2.50
end

label var time " in mins" // column label


gen no=_n
bysort user (no): gen session=1 if _n==1 | time[_n-1]>5 & !missing(time[_n-1]) // _n means current observation
bysort user :  replace session=sum(session)
sort no
drop no
```